# Identificar automaticamente pontos de influência em uma regressão

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

Sempre que fazemos uma regressão linear, precisamos verificar se as hipóteses assumidas para o modelo estão corretas. Uma das melhores maneiras de fazer isto é através de gráficos de diagnóstico. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
ajuste <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)

library(ggfortify)
autoplot(ajuste)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São quatro os gráficos de diagnóstico produzidos pela função `autoplot`. Alguns dos pontos destes gráficos são identificados como desviantes das hipóteses formuladas. Por exemplo, no QQ plot acima, os pontos 115, 135 e 142 são identificados como fora do esperado para os resíduos caso eles fossem distribuídos de acordo com a normal.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer esta identificação de forma automática no R? Como eu poderia pegar o output do `autoplot` (ou da própria função nativa `plot` do R) e identificar, para cada gráfico plotado, quais pontos violam as hipóteses do modelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, a função `autoplot.lm` do pacote `ggfortify` não veifica nenhuma regra para assinalar estes pontos.

Como pode ser visto [aqui](https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/master/R/fortify_stats_lm.R#L130#L131), ela apenas toma o número passado para o argumento `label.n` (que por padrão é `3`) e indica no gráfico aqueles pontos que possuem os *n* maiores residuos absolutos.

A função `autoplot` retorna um objeto de classe (**S4**) `ggfortify`. Este objeto tem slot chamado `plot` que guarda os 4 gráficos que aparecem quando o objeto for impresso. Neste slot o segundo elemento é o gráfico de tipo *qqplot*.

Como todo gráfico `ggplot` é uma lista com 9 elementos, podemos acessar o primeiro deles (data), que contém os dados, e então fazer os devidos cálculos.

O código abaixo mostra os 3 pontos com maiores resíduos absolutos:

```
ajuste <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)
library(ggfortify)
objeto_ggplot <- autoplot(ajuste, label.n = 10)

objeto_ggplot@plots[[2]]$data %>% 
  top_n(3, abs(.wresid)) %>% 
  select(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, .index)

  Petal.Width Petal.Length .index
1         2.4          5.1    115
2         1.4          5.6    135
3         2.3          5.1    142
```

Comment: Que decepcionante saber que a função retorna apenas os `label.n` resíduos mais extremos. Sempre achei que fosse outro critério de identificação.